Spotify api calls with flutter authorization problem returns PlatformException(CANCELED, User canceled login, null, null) even though user logs in
am using oauth2_client
below is the authorization code
 Future<void> authorizeUser() async {
    try {
      AccessTokenResponse? accessToken;
      SpotifyOAuth2Client client = SpotifyOAuth2Client(
        customUriScheme: 'my.music.app',
        redirectUri: 'my.music.app://callback',
      );
      var authResp =
          await client.requestAuthorization(clientId: client_id, customParams: {
        'show_dialog': 'true'
      }, scopes: [
        'user-read-private',
        'user-read-playback-state',
        'user-modify-playback-state',
        'user-read-currently-playing',
        'user-read-email'
      ]);
      var authCode = authResp.code;

      accessToken = await client.requestAccessToken(
          code: authCode.toString(),
          clientId: client_id,
          clientSecret: client_secret);
      print(accessToken);

      // Save access token, refresh token, and expiry date
      await userSharedPrefs.setAcessToken(accessToken.accessToken!);
      await userSharedPrefs.setRefreshToken(accessToken.refreshToken!);
      await userSharedPrefs.setExpiryDate(accessToken.expirationDate!);

      // Global variables
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

in androidmanifest
   <activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
           <data android:scheme="my.music.app" android:host="callback"/>
 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

i followed this article
note everything in the spotify dashboard is also correct
https://medium.com/@ssk_karna/spotify-api-in-flutter-ed8ebc8eba03
i tried doing this with my python api but i couldn't redirect to the flutter app
and i this same code worked before and i got my access token but when trying now it has become a problem
thank you in advance
